# Passing variable parameters to a method

Tags: java, methods, parameters

Hi is there any way for me to pass variable arguments to a method?

```
public void unMarshalling(String type, int number){

}
```

So that instead of int, I can make my method such that I am able to pass in float, double, string and other primitive data types(+ string). Any simple examples will be deeply appreciated! Thanks alot!

Comment: you mean : variable number of arguments, or *generic* variable arguments (which can be anything)?

Comment: Maybe `public void example(Object a){}` could do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try  this:

```
public void unMarshalling(Object ... params) {

}
```

Now you can pass any number of arguments of any type:

```
unMarshalling(23);
unMarshalling("Hello");
unMarshalling("Hello", 45.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void unMarshalling(String a, int b){}
public void unMarshalling(String a, float b){}
public void unMarshalling(String a, double b){}
public void unMarshalling(String a, String b){}
```

It will know which one to call based on the type.  If there's really only one function, you can put the 'meat' of it in String/int, then in String/float you can cast the float to an int as you like and call String/int.

```
public void unMarshalling(String a, float b)
{
  unMarshalling(a,(int)b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has var-args functionality, this means you can pass any number of argument in var-args of given type example -

```
  public void myMethod(int...args)
 {
 }
```

you can call this as methods as below -

```
  myMethod(3);
```

or          myMethod(3,4);

or myMethod(3,65,74); and so on.

You can specify any type of argument besides int.

please keep var-args as last argument if you have more then one argument.